# Ërror Message -The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required in MTM - Automation setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I am trying to set up MTM to run the automation test. I set the test controller and also the test agent and is all fine.

But when I run the test, I am getting an error message

**The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required.**

The reason for the above message is the access permission because the test controller is  setup using domainA/usernameA and the build server is in domainB and can be accessed using only usernameB which is specific to domainB

So the error I am getting is

**Could not use lab service account to access the build directory. Failure: Network path does not exist or is not accesible using following user https://domainB.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/a2c3c2CfC-XXXXX/_apis/build/builds/XXX/artifacts?artifactName=drop&%124format=zip using domainA\usernameA. Error Code: 67**

Could anyone please help me how to solve this issue. Any pointers will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS 2015 you can not use vNext build, it must be XAML build.
If you are using XAML build definion to build, go ahead and check permissions